# Instance for function with several classes

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to realize power function for my custom data type. I mean power (^) which has following signature:

```
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

And I mean that my data type `MyData` should be instance of `Num`, so I could write

```
x :: MyData
...
y = x ^ b
```

where b is some `Integral`. It's very easy when we need function of one class like

```
(+), (-), (*) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

We just write

```
instance Num MyData where
  (*) x y = someFunc x y
```

But I have no idea how to define it taking into account that there is also `Integral b`. That syntax should be like

```
instance (Integral b) => Num MyData b where
  (^) x y = someFunc x y
```

But I've tried a hundred of such variations and nothing works. Hours of googling also didn't help.

Comment: The `Integral` constraint has nothing to do with the `Num` constraint. If you define a `Num` instance for `MyData`, then you can write `x ^ b` as long as `b` is integral. `(^)` will use your `Num` instance, not the other way around.

Comment: Is your type actually a numeric type, or do you just want `(x ^ y)` as a short way to write "do `x` `y` times"? If the former, you should implement all of Num, not just one function, and if the latter you should use something other than `(^)`. For example, Semigroup appeals, if you want an effect like `stimes`.

Comment: If you ever want to use `MyData` for the exponent, then you need to *also* define an `Integral` instance for `MyData`.

Comment: @chepner If I just define (^) for my type as Num, I get error: No member "^" in class "Num". Maybe I need some extensions? About Integral for MyData - what for? I don't want to use MyData as exponent, only as basis

Comment: You don't define `(^)`; you get it for free as long as you have a `Num` instance for `MyData`.

Comment: @amalloy what to you mean by "type actually a numeric type"? I've defined (+), (*) and so on and I can write "x * x" or "x + x", it works, but I want also "x ^ 3".

Comment: You don't define (^); you get it for free as long as you have a Num instance for MyData - sounds like answer :) gonna check

Comment: Also, it looks like your error message (No member "x" in class "Y") comes from Hugs.  You may want to consider switching to GHC.  Hugs is really old (more than a decade since the last official release), and getting help can be tough.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr got it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do anything to define `(^)` for your data type; if your type has a `Num` instance, you get `x ^ b` for free, because `(^)` is defined for *any* type with a `Num` instance. (It basically just calls `*` a lot.)

Note that `(^)` is *not* a member of `Num` or `Integral`; it's just a standalone function whose type is constrained by both classes.

From https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#%5E

```
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
x0 ^ y0 | y0 < 0    = errorWithoutStackTrace "Negative exponent"
        | y0 == 0   = 1
        | otherwise = f x0 y0
    where -- f : x0 ^ y0 = x ^ y
          f x y | even y    = f (x * x) (y `quot` 2)
                | y == 1    = x
                | otherwise = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) x         -- See Note [Half of y - 1]
          -- g : x0 ^ y0 = (x ^ y) * z
          g x y z | even y = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) z
                  | y == 1 = x * z
                  | otherwise = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) (x * z) -- See Note [Half of y - 1]
```

`x0` is your `MyData` value; the only thing `(^)` ever does with `x0` (by virtue of it being passed as the `x` argument to `f` or `g`) is to multiply it by itself, so technically `(^)` will work as long as you have defined `(*)` in your `Num` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Unfortunatelly it was absolutelly not obvious :( I thought that correct way is some bonecrushing instance syntax variation